# Using matplotlib Polycollection to plot data from csv files

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I've been trying to make a diagram using PolyCollection very similar to this one:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html

The difference is, I want my code to read all CSV files from a folder and plot the data in them (not random numbers). Each CSV file contains a spectrum, i.e. two columns and a certain number of rows. I want the first row to be my x-values and the second row the corresponding z-values.

I tried this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

input_path = 'input'         
spectrumfiles = []
verts=[]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):    
    for name in files:
        if os.path.splitext(name)[1] == '.CSV' or os.path.splitext(name)[1] == '.csv':
            spectrumfiles.append(os.path.join(root,name)) 

zs = np.arange(len(files))                            

for name in spectrumfiles:
    spectrum = np.loadtxt(name, delimiter=',')
    #xs = spectrum[:,0]                   #I tried this first but then realised that "spectrum
    #ys = spectrum[:,1]                   #already has the needed shape               
    #verts.append(list(zip(xs,ys)))

    verts.append(spectrum)



poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=np.ones(len(verts)))      #I'm not too bothered with
poly.set_alpha(0.7)                                               #colours at the moment
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='y')

plt.show()
```

Now, the diagram I get is empty.

EDIT:
here are 4 sample [FILES](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ezyicvz0y3jwgjp/AADMBoM2p2IwondJsWiNjIyra?dl=0)

EDIT2:
here are some links to related questions on stackoverflow.
 - [Matplotlib plot pulse propagation in 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240633/matplotlib-plot-pulse-propagation-in-3d)
 - [Waterfall plot python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209646/waterfall-plot-python)

Comment: just check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622057/plotting-3d-polygons-in-python-matplotlib I am clueless

Comment: there seem to be a couple of questions on here about PolyCollection. But I'm clueless, too. I'm adding them into my original question.

Comment: What is the shape of `verts`? Also, does your data have any NaNs or other bad data in it?  That would mess things up.

Comment: shape(verts) returns (4L, 3449L, 2L), so that's 4 spectra with 3499 rows and 2 columns each. There are no NaNs in there and plotting each spectrum individually with matplotlib.pyplot.plot works just fine.

Comment: When I took your code and replaced the file reads with random numbers (e.g. `spectrum = np.random.rand(100,2)`) it worked fine. I'll see what your reads do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, easy fix - your only problem is that because you added the PolyCollection to your axes yourself, it doesn't automatically scale the x/y/z limits to appropriate values (still shows between 0 and 1).  For the data you have, if you add the following lines:

```
ax.set_xlim(0,5000)
ax.set_ylim(0,len(spectrumfiles))
```

then your data will magically appear.

[image: data visible now]